# Modal con datatable dejo de funcionar repentinamente

Tags: jquery

Tenia un modal con un DataTable de Jquery y de repente aparece vacio, no se que toque, la verdad no recuerdo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como veran a la derecha crea el codigo de la tabla y todo:

Aqui el archivo modalart.js:

```js
var t;
    $('#resultadomodal').on( 'draw.dt', function () {
        t=  $('#resultadomodal').DataTable();
 $('#resultadomodal_filter input').focus();

  $('#resultadomodal_filter input').on('keypress', function(event){
   
     if (event.keyCode ===13){
        
           $('.cantidad:first').focus();
         }
     });});
$(document).ready(function() {

     $.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionn/views/modules/articulo/filtroP.php",
            data: { "tf": "todos"}, 
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success: function(data){
            
                 t=  $('#resultadomodal').DataTable({

    data:data,
                columnDefs: [
                { type: "num", symbols:"$" , targets: 3 }
            ],
 
        columns: [
        {data:"codalfa", title: "COD.:" },
        {"data": "nombre", title: "NOMBRE" },
        {"data": "marca", title: "MARCA" },
        {"title": "P/U" ,  render: function (data, type, row,meta) {
            return '<label class="editable">$ '+row.precio+'</label>';
         } },
        {"data": "detalle", title: "CAT.:" },
        {"data": "subcategoria", title: "SUBCAT.:" },
          {  title:"CANT",
              data:null,
                render: function (data, type, row,meta) {
            return "<input type='text' style='width:50px;' name='"+row.idproducto+"' class='cantidad' value='1' tabindex='3' placeholder='cant'/>"
   
            }},
               {  title:"AGREGAR",
              data:null,
                render: function (data, type, row,meta) {
            return "<a  class='btn btn-primary' onclick='agregarProducto("+row.idproducto+");' name='agregar' >+</a>"
   
            }}
    ], 
 
  
  
    language:{
                        "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
                        "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                        "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
                        "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                        "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                        "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                        "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                        "sInfoPostFix":    "",
                        "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
                        "sUrl":            "",
                        "sInfoThousands":  ",",
                        "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                        "oPaginate": {
                            "sFirst":    "Primero",
                            "sLast":     "Último",
                            "sNext":     "Siguiente",
                            "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                        },
                        "oAria": {
                            "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                            "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                        }
                        },
   
          responsive: true });

        },
    });
 
});
 function agregarProducto(idproducto){
    var cantidad=0;
    cantidad=$("input[name="+idproducto+"]").val();
    
    id=idproducto;
   
  
         if (cantidad!==""){
    var accion = "agregar";
 
    $.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionn/views/modules/facta/procesoFactA.php",
            data: {"accion":accion,"id":id,"cant":cantidad}, 
         

            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success:function(){
                window.location.href="index.php?controller=facturaa&action=index";
            },
           
        });





    
  } else{
    alert("ingrese cantidad");
  }

} 

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
 <div class="modal fade" id="modalstockprod" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg"style="width: 75%;">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
<h4 class="modal-title">BUSQUEDA DE ARTICULO</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">CERRAR</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg"style="width: 75%;">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
<h4 class="modal-title">BUSQUEDA DE ARTICULO</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">CERRAR</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModalCC" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg"style="width: 75%;">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
<h4 class="modal-title">CUENTAS</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-bodyCC">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">CERRAR</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Como veran tengo 3 modales en el archivo tempolate.php, el general. no se si tiene algo que ver.
Si creo la tabla de prueba funciona perfectamente:

[js bin](http://live.datatables.net/puxiyotu/1/edit)

Comment: En la pestaña de Consola te da algun error?

Comment: No. Ninguno..al contrario me muestra el array de productos que deberia cargarse en la tabla

Comment: no veo el error, no veo donde se genera la tabla con el id resultadomodal, pero puedes probar a generar el datatable dentro del document.ready, porque creo que puede ser que intenta hacer la tabla datatable antes de que este creada

Comment: Esta dentro del ready en el pedido ajax. el codigo de arriba es para focalizar en buscar. Pero fue repentino probe con toros navegadores

Comment: pues a simple vista no lo veo, pero el error esta al generar el datatable porque no genera la tabla

Comment: En la estructura html de la consola aparece la tabla con head y body, no entiendo porque dejo de funcionar. lo unico que obsevo es:jquery-3.3.1.js:9488 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.